# I can't get value of base class field from child class object in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
using System;                   
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        
         CloudCollectionHelper cloudHelper = new CloudCollectionHelper();
         SlackHelper slackHelper = new SlackHelper();
        
        cloudHelper.DatabaseID=12345;
        Console.WriteLine(slackHelper.GetSlackPageTokens());

    }
    
    class CloudCollectionHelper
    {
        public  long DatabaseID { get; set; }
        
    }
    class SlackHelper:CloudCollectionHelper
    {
        
        public long GetSlackPageTokens()
        {
            return DatabaseID;
        }
    }
}
```

current output: 0
Expected Output: 12345

I need output 12345 because DatabaseID from the cloudhelper so i need that databaseID in the slackhelper.

this is my c# online compiler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QNQeEX

Comment: Inheritance alone won't help you to *inherit* value: assigning it in one instance will not affect another. Unless those are `static` members ([directly](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oduJpF) or if you use static member to synchronize instance members). Maybe you need a wrapper or one of common [patterns](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/csharp)? Perhaps it's worth explaining what which class will do and why. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295).

Answer (score 1):

The child class does not get the assigned values from the base class. Becouse there can be mutliple instances from it. For example, if you have

```
...
CloudCollectionHelper cloudHelper1 = new CloudCollectionHelper();    
CloudCollectionHelper cloudHelper2 = new CloudCollectionHelper();
cloudHelper1.DatabaseID = 1234;
cloudHelper2.DatabaseID = 6789;
Console.WriteLine(slackHelper.GetSlackPageTokens()); //It would not know, what value to use.
...
```

The best way would be assigning the value directly to the child class or using the static modifier.

Edit:
Best way if you need to take this value from the child class for whatever reason would be doing something like this:

```
...
CloudCollectionHelper cloudHelper = new CloudCollectionHelper();
cloudHelper.DatabaseID = 12345; //First assign the needed Value
SlackHelper slackHelper = new SlackHelper(cloudHelper); //then create a new instance from the child class
...
```

and add the constructor from the SlackHelper child class like this:

```
class SlackHelper:CloudCollectionHelper
{
    public SlackHelper(CloudCollectionHelper cloudHelper)
    {
         this.DatabaseID = cloudHelper.DatabaseID;
    }
    ... //Do everything else what this class needs here
}
```

If the Value from cloudHelper.DatabaseID can update during the runtime, you will need a event to update the child class. It still isn't the best way to do this, because the DatabaseID value is already public and can be accessed without the child class.

Edit 2:
Like I already told you in the comments, you could also avoid this problem with the static modifier. But this will effect every instance made from the CloudCollectionHelper class. As soons as you make it static, this will only hold 1 possible value for all instances.

(Please keep in your mind to use a comment if needed or best case, just avoid Magic numbers)

Comment: sorry its the wrong answer, we need cloudhelper value in slackhelper

Comment: You do know, that a child class does not know assigned values from the base class if they are not static? You could possibly also add a Constructors and give the child class the right values that way.

Answer (score 0):

The property of your Object slackhelper has not been affected.
You don't need to create a CloudCollectionHelper Object.

```
SlackHelper slackHelper = new SlackHelper();        
slackHelper.DatabaseID=12345;
Console.WriteLine(slackHelper.GetSlackPageTokens());
```

Comment: I have 1000 field in cloudhelper so I am not going to write slackHelper.DatabaseID=12345;

Please give me other solutions

Answer (score 0):

You should create this property inside the class to allow to read the Database ID

public long GetSlackPageTokens()
{
return base.DatabaseID;
}